# Yahoo! Mail HTML Email Alignment Issue can't align to center

Tags: html, email, templates, html-table, yahoo-mail

I have designed a email template but I am facing alignment issue on iPhone 5 and yahoomail .The contents could not be aligned to center. I am using reply manager to send email template.

Heres my code :

```
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table align="left" border="1" style="width:32%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><p><a href="#"><img alt="" src="http://websamplenow.com/30/logoloftems/images/brochure.jpg" style="height:157px; width:170px" /></a></p></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:14px">Handing out brochures is a very cost-effective way to advertise your brand.</span></p></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;
                                                <table align="center">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/brochuresamples.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/readmore.jpg" /> </a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- End Image 1 -->

                        <table align="left" style="width:2%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <table align="left" border="1" style="width:32%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><p><a href="#"><img alt="" src="http://websamplenow.com/30/logoloftems/images/imggz2.jpg" style="height:157px; width:170px" /></a></p></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:14px">Wow clients by using an animated logo for your website or email.</span></p></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;
                                                <table align="center">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="text-align:center"><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/webdesign.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/readmore.jpg" /> </a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- End Image 2 -->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <table align="left" style="width:2%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <table align="left" border="1" style="width:32%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><p><a href="#"><img alt="" src="http://websamplenow.com/30/logoloftems/images/invite.jpg" style="height:157px; width:170px" /></a></p></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:14px">Promoting events means attracting people. You need attractive designs!</span></p></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;
                                                <table align="center">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/stationery/promotionsamples.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/readmore.jpg" /> </a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- End Image 3 -->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- 3Column ends --><!--1 img starts--></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="width:600px">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/stationery.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/moreinfo.jpg" style="width:60%" /></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--1 img ends--><!--clients logo starts--><!--1 img ends--><!--clients logo starts--></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/fc_all.jpg" style="width:600px" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/microsoft.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/fc_microsoft.jpg" /></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/gillette.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/fc_gilette.jpg" /></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/oreck.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/fc_oreck.jpg" /></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/whirlpool.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/fc_whirlpool.jpg" /></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/ge.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/fc_bluething.jpg" style="height:37px; width:98px" /></a></td>
                                    <td dir="rtl"><a href="http://www.logoloft.com/oprah.html"><img src="http://websamplenow.com/129/ems1/images/fc_oprah.jpg" style="height:37px; width:126px" /></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The button 3 boxes are not aligned to center.

[image: AS you see on the image I cant align it to center on yahoo email template]

Can anyone help me to solve it out?